# Problema con plugin kartik editable en yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Buenas estoy utilizando el plugin de kartik, editable, en el framework Yii2 y a la hora de intentar modificar el valor del campo, que muestro con el citado plugin, me da el siguiente error:

SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

EL código de la vista es:

```
   $editable = Editable::begin([
                'model' => $model2,
                'attribute' => 'estado',
                'size' => 'md',
                'format' => 'button',
                'data'=> 'json',
                'editableValueOptions' => ['class' => 'card p-3'],

            ]);
        Editable::end();
```

Y la acción en el controlador correspondiente es:

```
public function actionEditableDemo()
    {
        $model = new Usuarios(); // your model can be loaded here
        \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        var_dump($model);
        die;
        // Check if there is an Editable ajax request
        if (isset($_POST['hasEditable'])) {
            // use Yii's response format to encode output as JSON

            // read your posted model attributes
            if ($model->load($_POST)) {
                // read or convert your posted information
                $value = $model->estado;

                // return JSON encoded output in the below format
                return ['output' => $value, 'message' => ''];

                // alternatively you can return a validation error
                // return ['output'=>'', 'message'=>'Validation error'];
            }
            // else if nothing to do always return an empty JSON encoded output
            else {
                return ['output' => '', 'message' => ''];
            }
        }

        // Else return to rendering a normal view
        return $this->render('view', ['model' => $model]);
    }
```

Por otro lado, si realizo un bugeo d ela petición ajax en mozilla obtengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: error producido]

Comment: ¿Qué tiene que ver con Laravel?

Comment: cierto, perdona.

Comment: Para empezar no debería ser un `'json'` en data, sino un array, revisa la documentación